# Aggregating two rows based on condition of different ID in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I am dealing with a dataset of players statistics for a sport. There is an error in the data where one week a player who doesn't exist, has been attributed the data that belongs to a real player. I need to aggregate the two players data and delete the instance of the false players' row.

I need to adjust my preprocessing code to accommodate this so when I scrape future weeks data then I don't need to make manual adjustments.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Bob","Ben","Bill"),
                 Team = c("Dogs","Cats","Birds"),
                 Runs = c(6, 4, 2)
```

I'd like to do something along the lines of aggregating the two rows based on their `df$Name` e.g. when `df$Name == "Bob" & df$Name == "Bill"` aggregate columns `[3:40]` -- these are my columns with numeric statistics, `[1:2]` have `df$Name` and `df$Team`.

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the type of aggregation you are trying to do. This looks like a perfect use of the `group_by` from the `dplyr` package. Consider the `CO2` data set.

```
library(dplyr)

CO2 %>% 
 group_by(Plant) %>% 
 summarise(
     n = n(), #Calculate number of rows in each group
     meanUptake = mean(uptake) # Aggregate data and take mean for each group
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Here we take each group, in your case above it would be name. In the summarise, if you wish to include extra information (like team) include it within the summarise.